# On Codeship CI I get: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'execFileSync'`

Tags: node.js, typescript-typings, codeship

I am using node 7.1 with TypeScript to build a command-line utility.  In my tests I invoke it using 'execFileSync'.

https://github.com/TheSwanFactory/maml/blob/script-expressions/test/syntax/script-spec.ts

```
import * as cp from "child_process";
...
const result = cp.execFileSync(hc_bin, args);
```

This runs fine on my local machine, but fails on the CodeShip CI with:

https://app.codeship.com/projects/194564/builds/21914340

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'execFileSync'
```

I have verified that the proper @types/node typings module is being installed.  I have tried to lock all my npm versions so the environment should be the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The build you linked to has an explicit `nvm install 0.10` listed as step 8 and runs on NodeJS 0.10.48 because of this. If you remove that command or adapt it to switch to Node 7.x it will very likely work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and switched to CircleCI.  The mysterious problem disappeared.